# passing array to webmethod using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to pass an array to webmethod using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "somepage.aspx/somemethod",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: Please see this answer for a working example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971393/passing-array-of-strings-to-webmethod-with-variable-number-of-arguments-using-jq/7972325#7972325

Answer (score 2):

just arrays...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "somepage.aspx/somemethod",
    data: "a[1]=1&a[2]=2&a[3]=3",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

you might do also on objects...

```
var myObject = {
  a: {
    one: 1, 
    two: 2, 
    three: 3
  }, 
  b: [1,2,3]
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "somepage.aspx/somemethod",
    data: decodeURIComponent($.param(myObject)), // a[one]=1&a[two]=2&a[three]=3&b[]=1&b[]=2&b[]=3
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

you can look at more options of [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), these includes `data`

Comment: Good answer Reigel. OP, please see the `data` option: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: the webmethod has the following signature but it is not getting called:
[WebMethod]
public static string somemethod(string[] arg)
{

}

Comment: what scripting language are you using? ASP.NET?

Comment: I have the js file which contains:

var array = new Array();
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "somepage.aspx/somemethod", 
    data: array
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json" 
}); 

and the method in the aspx.cs:

 [WebMethod] public static string somemethod(string[] arg) { }

Comment: Reigel - can u please show me the signature of your "somemethod" method would be?

Comment: I'm curious. are you in PHP? ASP.NET? and what are you expecting for `somemethod`?

Comment: it is asp.net (Please see my previous reply - 33 minutes ago)

Comment: How do you get the query string from ajax if the "somemethod" method is signed by static attribute? but on the other side if the "somemethod" is not signed by static attribute, it won't get called.. so confusing... :(

Answer (score -1):

I use something similiar to the following method

```
var your_array = new array();
your_array[0] = 1;
your_array[1] = 2;

var data = { numbers: [] };

data.numbers = your_array;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "somepage.aspx/somemethod",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data = json_data
});
```