# Passing an array to a web method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, webmethod

I am currently trying to pass an array that I have created in Javascript to my webmethod in my aspx.cs.

Heres what I have:

JAVASCRIPT

```
function callServer(requestMethod, clientRequest) {


    var pageMethod = "Default.aspx/" + requestMethod;
    $.ajax({
        url: pageMethod,   // Current Page, Method  
        data: JSON.stringify({ request: clientRequest }), // parameter map as JSON  
        type: "POST", // data has to be POSTed  
        contentType: "application/json", // posting JSON content      
        dataType: "JSON",  // type of data is JSON (must be upper case!)  
        timeout: 60000,    // AJAX timeout  
        success: function (result) {
            ajaxCallback(result.d);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(status + " - " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}



function myButtonCalls()
{
var values=[];
values[0] = "Hello";
values[1] = "goodbye";

callServer("myMethod", values);
}
```

ASPX.CS

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string myMethod(string[] request)
        {
return "This is test";
    }
```

It fails before it even gets to my web method. I know this code works for regualr strings but The ajax code that uses JSON doesnt see to want to work with arrays.

Any ideas of what i need to change?

Thanks

Comment: Try debuging your ajax request with Developer Tools in chrome or Firefox. Either one should tell you what response you're getting from the server.

Comment: I'll admit I'm not familiar with the server side of this, but does this post help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191317/passing-array-to-webmethod-using-ajax

Comment: @dfreeman it does thanks, It lead me to another question in that post which had exactly what i needed :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing array of strings to webmethod with variable number of arguments using jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971393/passing-array-of-strings-to-webmethod-with-variable-number-of-arguments-using-jq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the aspx.cs, I needed to accept with type list not array. Thanks for the comments!